# Sails WaterlineORM .populate() with limited attributes

Tags: sails.js, waterline

When we use WaterlineORM .populate() query we get all the attributes of the populated association.

**eg:**

```
User.find({name:'Finn'}).populate('dad').exec(function (err, usersNamedFinn){
    if (err) {
        return res.serverError(err);
    }
    return res.json(usersNamedFinn);
});
```

**Response:**

```
[
  {
    id: 7392,
    age: 13,
    name: 'Finn',
    createdAt: Wed Dec 25 2003 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST),
    updatedAt: Wed Feb 12 2016 18:06:50 GMT-0600 (CST),
    dad: {
      id: 108,
      age: 47,
      name: 'Joshua',
      createdAt: Wed Dec 25 1969 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST),
      updatedAt: Wed Jan 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST),
      dad: null
    }
  },
]
```

I need to **get in the response only the name and the id of the populated 'dad' association** (i.e. remove the other attributes of dad from the response)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Detailed information here https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/919

Seems like it has been added in v0.12.3

```
populate('relation', { select: ['wantedFields', ...] });
```

Comment: I use v0.12.4 but it still populates all fields when I used `populate('dad', { select: ['name', 'id'] });`

Comment: I have v0.12.4 and I tried this `populate('dad', { select: ['id', 'name'] });` but it did not make any difference. Still populating all the fields.

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera I hear you, however the solution I propose should work  according to the sails team. You should file a bug/issue on their github page.

Comment: I made some tests. It works currently only with a population of one-to-many relationship.

I made a pull request to solve the one-to-one relationship issue:
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/1613

Answer (score 0):

in your Model you can write a toJson() method that will manipulate the object:

```
toJSON() {
  // getting the object...
  let obj = this.toObject();

  // removing some attributes...
  delete obj.createdAt;
  delete obj.updatedAt;

  return obj;
}
```

and then into the Controller after the "populated" query results you can do:

```
.exec(function(err, usersNamedFinn){
  if(err){
    return res.negotiate(err);
  }

  return res.json(usersNamedFinn);
});
```

Hope this could help you